# x11 XChangeProperty fails with BadValue

Tags: window, fullscreen, x11, xlib

I am trying to create a fullscreen window with X11. I managed to get a basic window and event handling. According to [this](https://www.tonyobryan.com//index.php?article=9) I have to use the property name "_MOTIF_WM_HINTS" in order to hide window decorations, along with the custom type `Hints` (wherever that may reside or is user created). Nevertheless I found a list of property names [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2507144) but when I try using a simple one like "_WM_NAME" or "_NET_WM_NAME" I get a `BadValue` error.

I'm on Wayland currently but I do have installed [xorg-xwayland](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xorg-xwayland/).

Specificaly i get this error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  18 (X_ChangeProperty)
  Value in failed request:  0x8
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  17
```

The code in question is below:

```c
void fgd_window_toggle_fullscreen(fgd_window_t* win) 
{
    Display* display        = win->dsp; 
    Window   window         = win->window;
    int      screen_id      = win->screen_id;   
    fgd_window_info_t* info = &win->info; 
    
    info->is_fullscreen = (info->is_fullscreen == 1) ? 0 : 1;
    
    if (info->is_fullscreen) 
    {   
        Atom name_property = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_NAME", False); 
        
        if (name_property == None) 
        {
            printf("Failed to create property.\n");
            return;
        }
        
        unsigned char some_text[21] = "My fullscreen window.";
        
        XChangeProperty(display, 
                        window, 
                        name_property, 
                        name_property,
                        PropModeReplace,
                        8,
                        some_text, 
                        10);
        
        int video_modes_count = 0; 
        XF86VidModeModeInfo** infos = NULL;
        
        XF86VidModeGetAllModeLines(display, 
                                                   screen_id, 
                                                   &video_modes_count,
                                                   &infos);
        printf("Number of video modes: %d\n", video_modes_count);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < video_modes_count; idx++) 
        {
            XF86VidModeModeInfo* current_info = infos[idx];
            
            printf("ModeInfo[%d] = (%d, %d)\n", idx, current_info->hdisplay,
                   current_info->vdisplay);
        }
        // Switch to another video mode so we can fullscreen the window.
        XF86VidModeModeInfo* video_mode = *infos;
        XF86VidModeSwitchToMode(display, screen_id, video_mode);
        // Move the window to top left corner.
        XF86VidModeSetViewPort(display, screen_id, 0, 0);
        // Resize the window to the coresponding dimensions.
        XResizeWindow(display, window,info->max_width, info->max_heigth);
        
        XFree(infos);
    }
    else
    {
        int width_center  = (info->max_width  >> 1) - (info->width  >> 1);
        int heigth_center = (info->max_heigth >> 1) - (info->heigth >> 1);
        
        XResizeWindow(display, window, info->width, info->heigth);
        XMoveWindow(display, window, width_center, heigth_center);
    }
    
}
```

Is this a code related problem or my display manager is interfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! It seems that the client needs to call `XSendEvent` and it can't be done through `XChangeProperty`.

According to [this](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#idm45578527854784) the first 4 bytes of the `data` union can be:

```
_NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE        0    /* remove/unset property */
_NET_WM_STATE_ADD           1    /* add/set property */
_NET_WM_STATE_TOGGLE        2    /* toggle property  */
```

```c
void toggle_fullscreen(Display* dpy, Window win, b32* fullscreen)
{
    
    XClientMessageEvent msg = {
        .type = ClientMessage,
        .display = dpy,
        .window = win,
        .message_type = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_STATE", True),
        .format = 32,
        .data = { .l = {
                *fullscreen,
                XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN", True),
                None,
                0,
                1
            }}
    };
    
    XSendEvent(dpy, XRootWindow(dpy, XDefaultScreen(dpy)), False, SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask, (XEvent*) &msg);
    
    *fullscreen = !(*fullscreen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maximize the window, I could provide another way to do this.

```
int MaximizeWindow(Window window)
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XClientMessageEvent ev = {};
    Atom wmState = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
    Atom maxH = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ", False);
    Atom maxV = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT", False);

    if (wmState == None)
        return 0;

    ev.type = ClientMessage;
    ev.format = 32;
    ev.window = window;
    ev.message_type = wmState;
    ev.data.l[0] = 1;
    ev.data.l[1] = maxH;
    ev.data.l[2] = maxV;
    ev.data.l[3] = 1;

    int rv =  XSendEvent(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), False,
                      SubstructureNotifyMask,
                      (XEvent *)&ev);
    XFlush(display);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return rv;
}
```

Window handle is given to this function as an argument.

I created one [git repo](https://github.com/renjuashokan/x11Test) with this and another examples.